# Uncaught TypeError: can't access property "map", of *** is undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, rest

I am trying to display some information in my react functional component but for some reason it does not fetch the information before the component is rendered and the console throws me the error as shown above.

The REST API call does not throw any errors, I tested it using postman and it fetches the information without any issues.

see code below:

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { useSelector } from 'react-redux';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import { useParams } from 'react-router-dom';



const Checkout = (props) => {

    // fetching redux status
    let user = useSelector(state => state.loginStatus.user)
    let loginStatus = useSelector(state => state.loginStatus.isLoggedIn)

    let stringNight = props.lengthStay > 1 ? 'nights' : 'night';

    const params = useParams();
    //console.log(params.hotel_id   )

    let [room, setRoom] = useState()
    console.log(room)


    console.log(
        'Props in checkout',

        'length', props.lengthStay,
        'StartDate', props.startDate,
        'endDate', props.endDate
    )


    useEffect(() => {
        let url = `http://localhost:5000/rooms/${params.hotel_id}/${params.room_id}`;
        fetch(url).then((response) => {
            response.json().then((data) => {
                setRoom(data);
            }).catch((error) => {
                console.log(error);
            });
        })
    }, [])


    return (
        <div className='checkout-container'>
            {loginStatus === true && <>
                <h2>Your Booking details</h2>
                <section className='booking-details'>
                    <div className='check-in-out'>
                        <h5>Check in</h5>
                        <p>{props.startDate.toString().slice(0, 10)}</p>
                        <h5>Check out</h5>
                        <p>{props.endDate/*endDate.toString().slice(0, 10)*/}</p>
                        <h6>Total length of stay:</h6>
                        <p><strong>{props.lengthStay} {stringNight}</strong></p>
                    </div>
                    <div className='room-selection'>
                        <h5>Your room selection:</h5>
                        {room.map((r) => (
                            r.room_name
                        ))}
                    </div>
                    <div className='room-pricing'>
                        <h5>Your price summary:</h5>
                        {room.map((r) => (
                            r.room_rate * props.lengthStay
                        ))}
                    </div>
                </section>
                <section className='hotel-details'>
                    <h6>Hotel</h6>
                    {room.map((r) => (
                        r.hotel_name

                    ))}
                    {room.map((r) => (
                        r.location_name

                    ))}
                    {room.map((r) => (
                        r.country

                    ))}
                </section>
            </>}
        </div>
    );
};

export default Checkout;
```

Comment: on first render `room` isn't defined, the useEffect runs *after* the first render

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're trying to call `.map` on `room`:

```
room.map((r) => (
```

But what is `room`?:  Its initial value is `undefined`:

```
let [room, setRoom] = useState()
```

If `room` should always be an array, initialize it to an array:

```
let [room, setRoom] = useState([])
```

Alternatively, don't call `.map` on it if it's `undefined`:

```
room && room.map((r) => (
```

or perhaps:

```
Array.isArray(room) && room.map((r) => (
```

Comment: I must have forgotten to initialize it correctly.... Thank you !